# Stm32f103 code examples?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, stm32f10x, gcc

I'm starting with a small dev board using the STM32F103C8T6. The learning curve is steep and I'm trying to find some examples regarding peripherals.

I am using the Coocox IDE, the ARM GCC, and an ST-Link.

Is there any official code repo/docs for ARM GCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have ST's Standard Peripheral Libraries integrated into coocox?

There is a large, Doxygen-created help file included, along with many pieces of example code.

If you don't have them, you can find the Standard Peripheral Libraries [here](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/LN1939/PF257890).

ST has recently been pushing users to use their STM32Cube firmware development package instead of the SPL.  Some people love it; some stubbornly keep using the SPL. (I'm one of the stubborn ones).  If you want it, you can find STM32Cube [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF260820).